# Efficient algorithm to produce the n-way intersection of sorted arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, intersection, sorting

I need to produce the intersection between some sorted arrays of integers in C. I know how to find the intersection between two sorted arrays, but I need to do this for more than two arrays, efficiently and without prior knowledge of the number of arrays. I can impose a sensible limit on the maximum number - let's say ten for now. These arrays could be anywhere from a few items to a couple of hundred thousand items long, and are by no means necessarily the same length.

Pseudo-code for producing the intersection of two sorted arrays:

```
while i < m and j < n do:
    if array1[i] < array2[j]:
        increment i
    else if array1[i] > array2[j]: 
        increment j
    else 
        add array1[i] to intersection(array1, array2)
        increment i
        increment j
```

I am working with C, and I am after a clear explanation rather than code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that all your arrays are sorted. Lets assume we have arrays `A_1` to `A_n`. Have a counter for each array (thus, we have `n` counters `i_1` to `i_n`, just like you did it for two arrays).

Now we introduce a minimum-heap, that contains the whole arrays in a manner such that the minimum array is that array with the currently lowest number pointed to by the corresponding pointer. This means, we can at each moment, retrieve the array with the currently lowest number pointed to.

Now, we extract the minimum array from the heap and remember it. We go on extracting the minimum array as long as the number pointed to stays the same. If we extract *all* arrays (i.e. if all arrays have the same currently lowest pointed to number), we know that this number is in the intersection. If not (i.e. if not all arrays do contain the same currently lowest pointed to number), we know that the number we are currently examining can not be in the intersection. Thus, we increment all counters to the arrays already extracted and put them back into the heap.

We do this until we find one array's pointer reaching the array's end. I'm sorry for the undetailed description, but I do not have enough time to work it out in more detail.

### Edit.

If you have one array with very few elements, it might be useful to just binary-search the other arrays for these numbers or checking these numbers using a hash table.

Comment: Your description is more than adequate, however I am struggling to analyse the cost of this in comparison to the cost of repeated 2-way intersections. What are your thoughts on that?

Answer (score 4):

You already have the logic for intersect on two arrays, so just call it multiple times.

Your intersect logic,

```
while i < m and j < n do:
if array1[i] < array1[j]:
    increment i
else if array1[i] > array2[j]: 
    increment j
else 
    add array1[i] to intersection(array1, array2)
    increment i
    increment j
```

Encapsulate the above code in an `Intersect(int[] array1, int[] array2, int array1Length, int array2Length)`, that returns `int[]`. Call the method again on the result.

- Call1: `int[] result = Intersect(array1, array2, array1Length, array2Length)`
- Call2: `result = Intersect(result, array3, resultArrayLength, array3Length)`
- ...
- Call(n-1): `result = Intersect(result, arrayn, resultArrayLength, arraynLength)`

Possible optimizations:

- Continue with the calls only if the `resultArrayLength > 0` (otherwise the interestion is a null set).
- In the intersect method compare the last element of array1 with the first element of array2, i.e.

**EDITED**
    `if (array1[array1Length - 1] < array2[0])` return empty set (assuming that the arrays are sorted).

Comment: If your arrays are huge, say almost more than 2000 elements in each, this method is highly inefficient, as you have to make comparison with all the elements in each array. Possible optimization number 2 is good point, but that doesn't happen many times in real life scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

I would first intersect the two smallest arrays, then keep intersecting the result with the smallest intersected array left.  This guarantees that in every single intersect, one of the two arrays in question is no bigger than the smallest original array, which should save some time.

Comment: That could be a very useful hint.

Answer (score 1):

Use the mergesort approach.

Let the arrays be

1 2 3 4 5 6 7.

First find the intrsection of 1 2, 2 4, 5 6, For 7 donot do anything.
New sets:   A(1-2 Intersection)    B(3-4 Intersection)    C(5 - 6 Intersection)     7.
Repeat the above until u get one set.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably parallelize the computation as the intersection operation is commutative and associative. Have each thread compute the intersection of two arrays, that will reduce the number of array by two at each steps.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no constraint on space complexity then it will be easy to achieve using a hashmap. Assuming that numbers are not repeated in a same array.

Here is the python code for the same:

```
def intersection(arr_list):
    """
    >>> intersection([[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6]])
    [3, 4]
    >>> intersection([[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 6]])
    []
    """
    n = len(arr_list)
    ret = []
    d = {}
    for i in arr_list[0]:
        d[i] = 1
    for arr in arr_list[1:]:
        for j in arr:
            if j in d:
                d[j] += 1
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v == n:
            ret.append(k)
    return ret

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```